# Extracting exceptions from a ScheduledExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have a scheduled executor whose function connects to the internet and has the potential to throw and exception. This executor is part of an SDK I am developing, and the exception must be thrown to the implementing application.

I am currently doing the following,

```
Runnable task = new Runnable() 
{
    @Override
    public void run(){
        WindowCallback();
    }
};

_windowTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task,
        0, this.SQSWindow, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

where the WindowCallback() should throw the exception, but is currently catching the exception in order to make this code work properly.

I would like to do the following

```
Callable task = new Callable() 
{
    @Override
    public Object call() throws Exception{
        WindowCallback();
    }
};

_windowTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task,
        0, this.SQSWindow, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

but the Callable is not compatible with the scheduleAtFixedRate function of the executor.

How would I use a Callable that can throw my exception, in a recurring timer?

Comment: so throw an exception implicitly `throw new MyException("Hello Buddy")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once the task throws an exception, it's over for it: it won't be rescheduled. Even if this wasn't so, the exception would be lost witin the entrails of the `ScheduledExecutorService`. Your application would never find out about it since it happened on a separate thread.

Therefore you must work towards a design which catches everything *within* the task and dispatches the exception to the application by some mechanism, like calling a dedicated `ExceptionCallback`.

Comment: Actually adding an abstract method for handling the exception that is called within the catch block is a great way to handle this issue. It allows the developer to handle the exception as needed with their own implementation.

Comment: You mean adding the method to `Runnable`? But that gives you very little: just writing `public void run() { try { ...code... } catch (Throwable t) { ...handle...} }` is the same thing. So the abstract method just saves you from one try-catch.

Comment: No, I mean calling the abstract method in the catch block and passing the exception to that method. The important part of the abstract method was notifying the developer that an exception had occurred, and passing the information so that they can handle it as they see fit. The previous implementation absorbed the exception and the developer was never notified due to the exception being caught in the service.

Comment: What I was wondering is where the abstract method was declared.

Comment: It is declared in the service class, which also has several other abstract methods.

Comment: I see. Basically, you have `public void run() { try {service.process();} catch (Throwable t) {service.error(t);}}` which ricochets any exceptions `process` failed to catch back to the service class. Not bad, I suppose.